# Encoding Unicode URLs in UTF-8 XHTML documents

Tags: url, xhtml, utf-8

I would like to include the URI `http://beispiel.de/schnäppchen` into a link in a XHTML document, which is encoded in UTF-8.

Should I percent-encode the URL and write

```
<a href="http://beispiel.de/schn%C3%A4ppchen">foobar</a>
```

?
"ä" is a legal character in UTF-8 and therefore should be legal in XML/XHTML, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legal in (X)HTML, but not legal in an rfc2396 URL.

Note that the characters are converted using URL %-encoding, and not as SGML entities (with an `&`)

Comment: That also prevents problems, if the user agent auto-converts unquoted umlauts in URLs to ISO 8859-1 before the request.

Comment: To be clear, you can't have anything other than a limited subset of ASCII in URLs. If you want to construct a URL from a string with non-ASCII characters, common practice is to encode the Unicode string in UTF-8, then %-encode the bytes that aren't in the allowable ASCII range.